# Jquery how to click 2 buttons in one function? Help, Bootstrap included

Tags: jquery, function, button, click

I have such a code of the top bar of the page (navbar):

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar10">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Homepage</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#button1">First Button</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#button2">Second Button</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#button3">Third Button</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#button4">4th Button</a>
                </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And many lines on, I have the code for the gallery buttons. Each button displays different types of photos.

```
        <div class="gallery-menu text-center row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="button-group filter-button-group">
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <button data-filter=".photo_b" id="button1">First Gallery</button>
                    <button data-filter=".photo_d" id="button2">Second Gallery</button>
                    <button data-filter=".photo_c" id="button3">Third Gallery</button>
                    <button data-filter=".photo_a" id="button4">4th Gallery</button>
                    <button class="active" data-filter="*" id="button5">All photos</button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks to this code, when I click on the main bar in "First Button", thanks to "# button1" we go down to the "First Gallery" section, but nothing happens. I would like it to work so that when I click on "First Button" also at the same time, you click "First Gallery"

I tried many ways, such as:

```
    $( "#button1" ).click(function() {
$( this ).addClass('active');
});
```

but it does not work.
you can do it any way you like, it does not have to be jquery, if it works, because I've given up...
I am asking for help, thank you and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITTED:

```
$("a[href='#button1']").click(function(e) {
    $($(this).attr("href")).click();
});
```

Comment: Do u really think that will helps me?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get your question first, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly, you should select all `a` tags which their `href` attribute **starts** with `#button` and then inside of their `click` listener you should use their `href` values as your desired button id to fire your buttons `click` function. Here is a code snippet of this approach:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
console.log($(this).html());
});




/////////////////////////////////////////////
//    The code you are looking for
/////////////////////////////////////////////


$("a[href^='#button']").click(function(e) {
let btnID = $(this).attr("href");
console.log("link clicked => " + btnID);
setTimeout(()=>$(btnID).click() , 100);
});
```

```css
.space{
height:350px
}
.space2{
height:50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar10">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Homepage</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#button1">First Button</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#button2">Second Button</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#button3">Third Button</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#button4">4th Button</a>
                </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="space"></div>
        
        
          <div class="gallery-menu text-center row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="button-group filter-button-group">
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <button data-filter=".photo_b" id="button1">First Gallery</button>
                    <button data-filter=".photo_d" id="button2">Second Gallery</button>
                    <button data-filter=".photo_c" id="button3">Third Gallery</button>
                    <button data-filter=".photo_a" id="button4">4th Gallery</button>
                    <button class="active" data-filter="*" id="button5">All photos</button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="space2">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**try it should be work....**    
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar10">
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Homepage</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#button1">First Button</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#button2">Second Button</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#button3">Third Button</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#button4">4th Button</a>
                    </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>


        <div class="gallery-menu text-center row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="button-group filter-button-group">
                    <div class="flex-container">
                        <button data-filter=".photo_b" id="button1">First Gallery</button>
                        <button data-filter=".photo_d" id="button2">Second Gallery</button>
                        <button data-filter=".photo_c" id="button3">Third Gallery</button>
                        <button data-filter=".photo_a" id="button4">4th Gallery</button>
                        <button class="active" data-filter="*" id="button5">All photos</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**// here is your script code...**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('ul li a').click(function(){
            var gallery_id = $(this).attr('href');
            if(gallery_id != "#"){
                $(gallery_id).click();  
            }
        })

        $("#button1").on('click', function(){
                console.log('clicked button1');
        })

        $("#button2").on('click', function(){
                console.log('clicked button2');
        })

        $("#button3").on('click', function(){
                console.log('clicked button3');
        })

        $("#button4").on('click', function(){
                console.log('clicked button4');
        })

        $("#button5").on('click', function(){
                console.log('clicked button5');
        })
    </script>
```